# img falls behind object(embedded youtube vid) with z-index attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, positioning

Im trying to place a png image over an object element containing a youtube video

here:

```
<object>
scripts...
</object>

<img src='src' style='position:absolute;top:-10px;z-index:99;'/>
```

the position property is not applied to the object and yet once the embedded video loads, it overlaps the img. It doesn't push the img down, it just overlaps it.

solution?

Comment: You have two typos in the `style`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

> wmode="transparent"